# How to configure htaccess to serve prerended page instead of dynamic page?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, seo, prerender

I try to configure apache, with .htaccess, to serve prerendered pages for search engine crawlers only. I thought I succeed until google register my page as http://mydomain.fr/prerender.

So google have well registered my prerendered page as mydomain.fr/prerender, but I want it to be registered as mydomain.fr/. This an issue because when users access it from search engine, they will go to the prerendered page which is not javascript-functionnal.

I should precise that when I test that configuration on localhost, apache did well serve my prerendered page on mydomain.fr/.

Here is my .htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Cache-Control "no-cache"
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

#Serving prerendered main page for crawlers
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (aolbuild|baidu|bingbot|bingpreview|adidxbot|msnbot|duckduckgo|mediapartners-google|adsbot-google|adsBot-google-mobile-apps|googlebot|mediapartners-google|teoma|slurp|yandex) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /prerender/index.html [L]

#Serving prerendered pages for crawlers
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (aolbuild|baidu|bingbot|bingpreview|adidxbot|msnbot|duckduckgo|mediapartners-google|adsbot-google|adsBot-google-mobile-apps|googlebot|mediapartners-google|teoma|slurp|yandex) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /prerender/$1/index.html [L]

#Redirecting to https
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#Giving full control to front-end routing
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . / [L]
```

/prerender is not even a route in my app, it's not handled by my front-end router (which redirect to /404), and it's not provided by my sitemap. And, if i understand well, this .htaccess does not redirect the request for crawlers, it only serve an alternative resource. I see no reason for google to register the /prerender route.

Comment: Little we can say here. You just state that the "prerender" route cannot be accessed. We can only take your word for that. Although it is obvious that this route _can_ be accessed, since the bot crawled it.

Comment: No, I didn't want to say it can't  be accessed. What I mean is that this route isn't specified anywhere on my website, not on a sitemap or as a link. But it can be access if you know there is a prerender/index.html resource. The only place I'm playing with the prerender/index.html resource is this htaccess, so it's probably due to that configuration